# Dynamic WCF service coupling on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, service

I am trying to build a service mechanism which should be add-on based and communicating through a publish subscribe system. It must be based on WCF services. 
What I have right now is a concept which I can't get to work so I decided to ask you because maybe I am going at this the wrong way (I only just started using WCF).

What I want to achieve is making a single core service with session persistency which can be extended by linking an unknown number of add-on services. I want to set up the publish subscribe system at runtime, not at buildtime, so the core-service should be able to detect what add-on services are available (using the web.config?) and then bind them to the message bus.

From the front end (ASP classic) it must be possible to access any .svc file but, maintaining session, each .svc file must be connected to the message bus.

All is hosted in a single IIS active directory.

Can you give me some hints as to where to look?

I am especially interesed in:

- WCF dynamic discovery
- WCF to WCF communication on the same host (in the same active directory even)

Thanks in advance, hope you can help!

**Update**

Thanks for your answers, I'll read up at the links you send me. I'll post my final concept solution here in due time for future reference.

Comment: A static service contract (operation & data contract) is a fundamental premise in WCF-based services. Have you looked at a more dynamic architecture like [hypermedia based applications?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) It seems you need an architecture where the service directs the client along a workflow given certain inputs. REST is much better suited to that type of application than soap based services.

Comment: No, I can't say that I have. To be honest, it did not even know it existed so thanks! Having read your links I have to conclude that my concept is far to complex for the application. So, turning the problem upside-down, I am going to test what will happen if I make a static WCF network and then just omit the DLL's on the server. I think I can detect that beforehand and would make the implementation a lot less complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents about Publish subscribe mechanism using WCF - WCF is not inherently built for pub/sub mechanism. It is built for Request/Response model of communication. Have a look at the NService Bus for pub/sub [here](http://nservicebus.com/)

Talking about Add on services on top of core service, I am not able to get What you want exactly ? Is it the Routing service which you want ? WCF 4 now provides routing service For more information look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) The link also talks in detail about the discovery mechanism in WCF 4.

Also have a look the Agatha framework which also have single WCF service and no. of request handlers where in the framework will decide which request handler to call based on each request.

Search for Agatha - Davy brion for more information

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to that! On publish-subscribe I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx) great article. I'm using it right now along with AutoResetEvent to sync messages and response messages which is working quite well for me.

Comment: As I am moving to another client and can't finish the project I think I will not spend time on investigating the question further. For this reason I will accept you answer as it provides the most reading material and useable hints.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem since I have one common WCF service but the implementation depends on the user's role so it was kind of difficult to do that at runtime.
I found this tutorial on the matter which runs great for my propouses: http://blog.micic.ch/net/dynamic-iis-hosted-wcf-service

I have tested in my env and is very powerful technique. Hope that helps you as well. Cheers.